# Connecting CCNA lab to home switch for desktop access

Tags: home-networking, cisco-router

SU Network Enthusiasts,

I'm a little lost on how to connect my CCNA lab to my home network. I <strike>can</strike> have diagrams of both to ease the burden of answering this broad question: how can I access both environments through one desktop with only one NIC?

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5XJI.jpg)

I have a console cable connection to R1 in the lab from the desktop for configuration and my desktop is on the home network subnet which only has one NIC. I have R1 connected to my home switch. My home switch and router appear to have recognized it automatically as a separate WAN. The trick I'm having difficulty working out is how to see the lab from the desktop.

I don't quite know what is pertinent information to provide to assist this along, but maybe some questions or simple suggestions can help me work this out on my own.

Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Ken

Comment: I guess you've already spent the money on the equipment, but what deterred you from using Packet Tracer, GNS3, NetSim, etc? Also, why are you wanting to connect the CCNA lab to your home network? If you're connected to R1 and all of the devices in the network can communicate, that's all you need? The ASA is also irrelevant if you aren't going for the CCNA security exam.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Part of my degree is certifications, particularly, this term contains Net+, Cloud+, CCNA, CCNA Security, and about 6 others. I'm also very tactile, so I "have" to touch...plus, Packet Tracer makes me want to commit homici...let's just say we had a falling out. I got the equipment on the cheap, so I'm very pleased with the ability to word hands-on.

Comment: The reason I want to connect from my desktop is to partly start my VPN project but to also enable ssh functionality so I can stop with the console port swapping. Knowing how to route between subnets should be something I remember, but that was years ago and I never mastered it. Now I'm here starting from almost ground zero to learn everything the right way for me, not for work, and not to just pass a test to prove I understand a concept, but to achieve mastery and add more tools to my personal toolkit. Also, I never said they can talk, I just stated my home router recognized a new WAN.

Comment: Could you explain more _why_ you say that "home switch and router appear to have recognized it automatically as a separate WAN"? The description does not make all that much sense, especially when applied to switches (which don't really care about "WANs").

Comment: But routers do care about WANs. The Gi0/0 interface from R1 is connected to my home switch, which did its job and the home router picked up the neighboring router from the lab automatically. And yes, it doesn't make sense because Cisco doesn't do anything automatically except with cdp, eigrp or administratively taking down a port, but here I am with a RV340 router that made a new WAN because it saw a new routing neighbor.

Comment: Most people just pick one, maybe two certifications to specialize in. You don't need all 6, that's for sure. Anyways, to answer your question. The best way would be to enable ssh on each of the devices. Since you have the console cable into R1, that would allow you to access that one. From there you could ssh around to each device. Do you know how to set that up?

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't really have a choice as it's a part of my degree plan.

Comment: I'm inferring here, but are saying that I should be able to function as I am now by simply configuring ssh? If that's true, then maybe I just needed to stay at it instead of not trusting in my home router throwing up that new WAN link; it really did surprise me, it being a RV340 small business router. I'll give it a go and post the results in a comment so you can post an answer.

Comment: @DrZoo Yes, you were correct. All the negotiations happened automatically between all the devices and all I needed to do was see who could talk to who (everyone) and then enable ssh. It was already working and I just didn't trust the ease of how it happened. To correct something I stated earlier, the second WAN is the one I setup to maintain my own IP space in my home network, I was just confused about it being present and assumed it belonged to my lab router. Since I can't mark a comment as an answer, please go ahead and reply with your suggestion from earlier and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to communicate with all of the devices, is to use the console cable and directly connect to R1. From there you can use the command `ssh X.X.X.X` to ssh into the device you wish.

To check that ssh is enabled on the device, use the command `show ip ssh` or `sh ip ssh` for the shorthand command. If ssh is enabled on the device, the output will show `SSH enabled - version X.xx` and display the authentication timeout time, and authentication retries number like so - `Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3`

Though you have a diagram of your network, if you're ever unsure of the neighboring devices IP address, you can use the `show cdp neighbor` command, which is enabled on all devices by default. You can also fine tune this command to specify the neighbor of a specific port or management interface. [show cdp neighbors documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/l2/show-cdp-neighbors.html)